# Create an Array of Tuples in Typescript

Tags: typescript, tuples

It's easy to create a generic pair type ( simplest possible Tuple ) i.e.

```js
type Pair<A, B> = [A, B]
```

The question is how to create an type which represents and array of such generic pairs.

The only requirement is for element in the array to be a pair. The type of the first element and the type of the second element ought to be polymorphic, `any` does not make the cut, otherwise this would be satisfactory:

```js
type Pair = [any, any]
type Pairs = Pair[]
```

Comment: Wait, why doesn't `Array<[any, any]>` work?  I don't understand what you mean by "polymorphic" here.

Answer (score 24):

`Pair<T, K>` is the same as `[T, K]` yes, it will do what you want but its syntactically unnecessary.

To create an array of tuples it just would be `Array<[TYPE, TYPE]>` or `[TYPE, TYPE][]`

Answer (score 15):

I feel like I am missing a nuance here..  But believe this is what you are asking for:

```
type Pair<T,K> = [T,K];
type Pairs<T,K> = Pair<T,K>[];

  const apple: Pair<number,number> = [2,3];
  const orange: Pair<number,number> = [3,4];
  const food: Pairs<number, number> = [apple, orange];
```